# Selecting columns from a subset based on the max of another column in the subset in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Biologist and mySQL (version 5.7.13) beginner here and I'm currently facing a task that I can't wrap my head around. I have a table that records sightings of individuals along with the time, an extract from the data looks like this:

```
Table "tblSightings"
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| id_individual | project | id_survey | Surveydatetime      |
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| A             |       1 | S1        | 2016-11-18 15:54:00 |
| B             |       1 | S1        | 2016-11-18 15:54:00 |
| C             |       1 | S1        | 2016-11-18 15:54:00 |
| A             |       1 | S2        | 2016-11-06 13:33:00 |
| B             |       1 | S2        | 2016-11-06 13:33:00 |
| X             |       1 | S2        | 2016-11-06 13:33:00 |
| A             |       2 | S3        | 2015-05-01 12:48:00 |
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
```

What I would like to do is create a query that lists the most recent sighting of an individual (Highest Surveydatetime of id_individual + project) along with the corresponding id_survey and all the other individuals that were sighted together with it during that sighting (GROUP_CONCAT(id_individual)). The desired result based on the example data here would be:

```
+---------------+---------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| id_individual | project | id_survey     | associates | latest              |
+---------------+---------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| A             |       1 | S1            | B C        | 2016-11-18 15:54:00 |
| B             |       1 | S1            | A C        | 2016-11-18 15:54:00 |
| C             |       1 | S1            | A B        | 2016-11-18 15:54:00 |
| X             |       1 | S2            | A B        | 2016-11-06 13:33:00 |
| A             |       2 | S3            |            | 2015-05-01 12:48:00 |
+---------------+---------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I did figure out how to get the latest Surveydatetime for each individual with

```
SELECT 
id_individual, 
project, 
MAX(Surveydatetime) AS latest 
FROM tblSightings 
GROUP BY id_individual, project;
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the corresponding "id_survey" for the column "latest" and thus also cannot figure out how to get all the id_individuals from a sighting for the GROUP_CONCAT for the associates column in the desired result. It doesn't work when I include id_survey in the SELECT as I also would have to put it in the GROUP BY, resulting in multiple rows for each individual again. Most answers for "max of subsets" I've found thus far do an INNER JOIN with a SELECT statement in it but I cannot get this to work at all...

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to write this query:

```
SELECT t1.id_individual, t1.project, ts.id_survey, t1.latest,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id_individual) AS associates

FROM tblSightings ts
    INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT 
            id_individual, 
            project, MAX(Surveydatetime) AS latest 
        FROM tblSightings 
        GROUP BY id_individual, project
    ) t1
        ON t1.id_individual = ts.id_individual
        AND t1.project = ts.project
        AND t1.latest = ts.Surveydatetime

    LEFT JOIN tblSightings t2
        ON ts.id_survey = t2.id_survey
        AND ts.project = t2.project
        AND t1.latest = t2.Surveydatetime
        AND t1.id_individual != t2.id_individual

    GROUP BY t1.id_individual, t1.project, ts.id_survey, t1.latest
    ORDER BY t1.latest DESC, t1.project, t1.id_individual, ts.id_survey;
```

**Explanation:**

To achieve the given format of results, we'd need to `JOIN` the same table thrice. The first is an `INNER JOIN` which is used to get `id_survey` of the record with highest timestamp per individual, per project. The second is to determine if there are any associates for a given individual. Since there may not be any associates at all (as seen for `S3`), we use here a `LEFT JOIN` instead. We also make it certain that this `LEFT JOIN` operates only upon those `id_individual` which are not the same as the individual whose record is being processed, but they're part of the same project and survey.

[**Demo link**](http://rextester.com/ATZYK24908)

Comment: Perfect, this works! Thank you very much! Now I really need to wrap my head around this, thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Thanks.. Glad to know!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select
        t2.id_individual, t2.project, t2.survey id_survey,
        (
            Select GROUP_CONCAT(tt.id_individual)
            From tblsightings tt
            Where tt.project = t2.project and tt.id_survey = t2.survey and tt.id_individual <> t2.id_individual
        ) associates,
        t2.maxdate latest
From
(
      Select t1.project, t1.id_individual, maxdate,
            (
                Select id_survey
                From tblsightings tt
                Where tt.project = t1.project and tt.id_individual = t1.id_individual and tt.surveydatetime = t1.maxdate
            ) survey
      From 
      (
          Select project, id_individual, max(surveydatetime) maxdate
          From tblsightings t1
          Group by project, id_individual
      ) t1
) t2
Order by t2.project, t2.id_individual
```

Data I used:

```
CREATE TABLE tblsightings 
(
  id_individual varchar(100),
  surveydatetime varchar(100),
  id_survey varchar(100),
  project varchar(100)

  );

INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("A","2016-11-18 15:54:00","S1","1");
INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("B","2016-11-18 15:54:00","S1","1");
INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("C","2016-11-18 15:54:00","S1","1");
INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("A","2016-11-06 13:33:00","S2","1");
INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("B","2016-11-06 13:33:00","S2","1");
INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("X","2016-11-06 13:33:00","S2","1");
INSERT INTO tblsightings (id_individual,surveydatetime,id_survey,project) VALUES ("A","2015-05-01 12:48:00","S3","2");
```

Comment: Thank you! The sub queries on their own work but when I put it together I get a "subquery returns more than one column" error. I'll keep trying though, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @Sam Hmm, ok. I think the cause is in the "survey" subquery. max(id_survey) instead of id_survey might solve that. However that would mean that there are multiple equal surveydates for some projects + id_individual which I assumed cannot be the case. Nevermind anyway, you already have a working answer. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I'll play around with it, I really want to understand how this all works. I'm doing ok on simple queries, joins etc. but this challenge really made my head hurt. Thank you very much for your effort!